# SQL Server : remove duplicates with MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a table, `Scores`, I want to select the `ID` for the `max(score)` for a given `GID`, but in the case of a duplicate score, I want it to return the ID for the `min(lastplayed)` date.

```
ID    GID   SCORE    LASTPLAYED
==    ===   =====    ==========
1     ABC    100     2017-12-13
2     ABC     95     2017-12-15
3     ABC    100     2017-12-22
```

I want ID = 1

Below is something like what I want except being ID is unique, every row is returned. Removing ID from the select will give me the highest score with the earliest date but unfortunately, that's not what I want.

The ultimate goal is to only return the ID column for row 1.

```
select ID, max(Score), min(LastPlayed) 
from Scores 
where GId = 'ABC' 
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ranking function like `row_number` in `order by`.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from tbl
order by row_number() over(partition by gid order by score desc,last_played)
```